No non-trivial integer solutions for $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=(2^n)^2$?
I am programming a transformation library utilizing unit quaternions for rotations. For testing, I was looking for exact unit quaternions that can be represented as floating point numbers (with finite binary fraction representation), so of the form $\frac a{2^n}+\frac b{2^n}i+\frac c{2^n}j+\frac d{2^n}k$. Setting the length to 1 means $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=(2^n)^2$. In order to avoid permutations and symmetries, I restricted the solutions to $0\leq a\leq b\leq c\leq d$.
I have searched up to $2^n=16384$ and found only the lame trivial solutions $a=b=c=0, d=2^n$ and $a=b=c=d=\frac {2^n} 2$.
Since I know some nice unit quaternions in base 10 (e.g. $0.1+0.3i+0.3j+0.9k$), I knew that there are finite fraction solutions in general. Just for fun I checked with denominator 37 and to my surprise found 38 solutions.
In order to properly quantify how disappointed I should be, I systematically computed the number of solutions with other denominators $p$, so $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=p^2$. I've run tests up to $p=1024$ and every denominator that is no power of two has tons of solutions! $p=945$ has 40600 solutions!
I also found the sequence of numbers of solutions in the OEIS.
Can someone prove that there is no non-trivial solution for powers of two? Or find one?

Not sure what you are calling "trivial".  $2^5=4^2+4^2+0^2+0^2$ is not in one of the forms you mention...is it trivial?  this question contains a proof that $2^{2k+1}$ can't be written as the sum of four non-zero squares....is that what you meant?

@lulu sorry I've made a silly mistake in the title, fixed it. By trivial I meant only the two forms I've mentioned. Yours would be a solution but I didn't mean to include odd exponents on the right hand side.

Not hard to show that all of $a,b,c,d$ are even (excluding some low $n$ cases) so you can divide both sides by $4$ to get an expression for $2^{2n-1}$, reducing to the odd case.

Here's a proof that there are no nontrivial solutions.
Consider the quantities $x=a^2+b^2$ and $y=c^2+d^2$. Let's divide out any shared factors of 2 between $x$ and $y$, resulting in $x'$ and $y'$, at least one of which is odd. Then we have $x'+y'=2^i$ for some integer $i$.
Note that any positive number that is the sum of two squares is of the form $2^m n$, where $n$ is 1 mod 4. This is true of $x$ and $y$, and also of $x'$ and $y'$.
We therefore know that $x' + y' \mod 4$ cannot be 0 mod 4, because one of $x'$ and $y'$ is 1 mod 4, and the other is not 3 mod 4. Thus, $i$ is either $0$ or $1$, giving either $x'=0$ and $y'=1$, or $x'=y'=1$.
Returning to $x$ and $y$, we find that either $x=0$ or $x=y$. Returning to $a,b,c,d$, we find that if $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=2^j$, then we either have $a=b=c=0$, $a=b=0 \,\&\, c=d$, or $a=b=c=d$.

Sorry, this is a bit hard for me to follow. I will try at some point and make this the accepted answer if I got it. For now, I have two proves I don't fully get but I will just believe you guys.

COMMENT.-Applying the known generalization of Pythagorean triples solving the equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^{i=k}x_i^2=x^2,$$ you have for the equation $$A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2=X^2$$ the solution $$(d^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)^2+(2ad)^2+(2bd)^2+(2cd)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are arbitrary parameters (four instead of the two for Pythagorean triples!).
It follows that if you solve first $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=2^n$ for some n, then you are done.
Now looking at your link of OEIS you can verify that for $n=2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512$ (there is not $n=2^m$ for $m\gt9$) there are only two solutions (which must be certainly the two you show in your post for the equation $A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2=(2^n)^2$.
$$******$$
Finally, you can see now that $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=(2^{n+1})^2=4(2^n)^2$$ which lets you to use induction to prove that always there are only two trivial solutions.
